# How would I set a variable to be equal to information from an API? (Js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roblox

How would I set a variable to be equal to information from this API?
→ https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails

For example, I want to create a variable with name "Value"
Looking at the API:

```
"439945661":["Silver King of the Night ","SKotN",163059,160000,160000,4,2,-1,-1,-1]
```

What this means:

```
[item_name, acronym, rap, value, default_value, demand, trend, projected, hyped, rare]
```

I want "Value" to be equal to the `value` from the API, so that value === 160000 (In this case).

I've tried to look up examples from others and other people with a similar problem but I just don't seem to get understand when comparing their problem to mine. Hopefully I made sense trying to explain my problem.

Note that I'm trying to create a discord bot that would grab a value from a specific item requested by the user, out of that API.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which will take the array and convert it into the variables that you specify at the indexes.

Below is an example of taking the array and mapping it into the variables and then using those variables to create an object.

```js
const cards = {
"439945661":["Silver King of the Night ","SKotN",163059,160000,160000,4,2,-1,-1,-1]
};

const cardsFormatted = Object.entries(cards).reduce((acc, [key, data]) => {
   const [item_name, acronym, rap, value, default_value, demand, trend, projected, hyped, rare] = data;
   acc[key] = { item_name, acronym, rap, value, default_value, demand, trend, projected, hyped, rare };
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(cardsFormatted);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This definitely helps, do you have any idea how I would get the const cards from the API ? So that when I ask for "Silver King of the Night" It will show me that string of information and in case I ask for a different item, it gives me it's corresponding info string ?

Comment: SO use fetch to get the api and you can use find() to loop through and get the value you are after.